# css selector understanding

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am trying to select the first immediate child `<p>` element of `<li>` element that contains an immediate `<ul>` child.

```
li>ul:parent>p:first-child
```

is what I have tried, thinking it will get the `li`'s with immediate `ul`'s then go back to the original `li`'s with the `:parent` selector then select the immediate `p`'s children that are first.

e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>SELECT ME!</p>
        <ul>
            <li><!--some more stuff-->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

following the comments I should say that I am using this in a jQuery selector and I found the `:parent` selector in the jQuery API pages.

Comment: CSS doesn't have parent selectors I'm afraid. This might do you:
ul > li > p + ul

Comment: There is no `:parent` selector

Comment: You will be able to do it in CSS4, but not now.

Comment: @dfsq Really? Do you have a link?

Comment: So you want the jQuery selector for this, not the CSS?

Comment: if there was a way to achieve this selection in both I would be happy to learn both, I am doing it in this instance in jQuery but I would like to be able to do it in pure css too if it is possible

Comment: @LinusCaldwell http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/

Comment: @dfsq thanx! I thought they will never implement because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that `li > ul:parent` will select the `<ul>` element, but specifying `> p:first-child` does not match anything, since your `p` element is within the `li`, not a direct descendent of the `<ul>`.

You can use jQuery's [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector for this:

```
$('li:has(ul) > p:first-child').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2JV5V/).

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible with pure CSS.

Comment: cheers, I thought the jQuery `TAG:parent` would select the parent of `TAG`

Comment: Yes, it does. My point is that in your markup, `ul > p:first-child` doesn't match any element.

Comment: I thought that the `ul:parent` resolved li` so `li>p:first-child` is ultimately what I was getting. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @BenM: "Yes, it does." If you mean yes, `TAG:parent` selects the parent of `TAG`... no, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
li > ul ~ p:first-of-type
```

select what you want? That should select `p` elements which are the first children-which-are-`p`, and which are *siblings* of `ul` elements which are direct children of `li`s. See [this post](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) on descendant and sibling selectors.

**Edit**: Looking closer I see this won't *quite* work with your setup, as the `p` would need to be after the `ul` in the source. Perhaps you can change your source order slightly?

Comment: `:first_child` should be `:first-child`, no?

Comment: `ul ~ p:first-child` doesn't make sense as a selector regardless of the setup anyway. Even if you change the source, the `:first-child` selector will probably be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting an id on the top-level `ul`, it will keep you from accidentally matching any `p:first-child` in nested `li`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpkp3/4/)

**JQuery**

```
$('#top>li>ul').parent().find('>p:first-child');
```

Comment: true but I want the `p` to be clickable to `slideToggle` the nested `ul`s I'm not sure whether I want it to be just the top level or all levels, probably all.